# $pdf->Image causing internal server error in ajax call, FPDF

Tags: php, ajax, fpdf

I am generating a multi cell table using FPDF library which is working perfectly. Now I want to add a logo at the top but `$pdf->Image` is not working for some reason.

I am generating this PDF via ajax call. Everything else was working but when I added `$pdf->Image` than I am getting internal server error in console. I tried this in an other file and it was working there and it only does not work in this ajax called function.

```
require 'fpdf181/html_table.php';
$pdf=new PDF_MC_Table('P','mm',array(280,300));
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',14);
$filename  = 'cert_'.uniqid('', TRUE).'.pdf';
$filename = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/wp-content/pdf/".$filename;
$pdf->Image('logo.png',60,30,90,0,'PNG');
$pdf->Output($filename, 'F');
```

I am sure it is only happening because of `$pdf->Image` as everything else was working correctly and when I comment out this line than again pdf start to generate correctly. I also tried to increase memory limit and max execution time but nothing is working.

Any suggestion regarding this will be appreciated.

Comment: First of all you should extract some error, try with `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` above your code, if you are on live site, you can add IP check.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. In cpanel this is the error I am seeing for this call.
[Tue Oct 29 04:01:57.937238 2019] [:error] [pid 86793:tid 47581130401536] [client 39.52.63.235:49916] PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in /home/mywebsite/public_html/php.ini on line 20, referer: http://domain/certifications/?target=person&certified=yes&pageSize=20&pageNumber=1&lastname=Abarca&country_text=United+States&state=CA